# How to call a partition of $X$ which consists of all singleton subsets of $X$?

Tags: combinatorics, terminology, set-partition

In other words, if $X$ is a set, then how do we call $Y=\{\{x\}:x\in X\}$?

$\{X\}$ is already named the trivial partition, so that cannot be it. Complete partition and total partition did not yield enough search results. Does it maybe not have a name?

A related question: does $Y$ exist for every $X$?

Comment: Only guessing: Something like *finest* partition or *complete* partition? Another possibility would be *singleton* partition.

Comment: +1 for "partition of singletons" or "singleton partition"

Comment: If you are inclined to give your own name, that's within the ambit of mathematical convention, provided you make the necessary definition.  I'd be tempted to call it an *atomic* partition (since none of the parts can be split).